# How to find the Camera Matrix and Camera Distortion file for detecting aruco markers?

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm trying to detect the location of Aruco Marker but I don't know how to find the Camera Matrix and Camera Distortion file. Can anyone tell how to calculate or find these files for my camera.

Answer (score 0):

You have to calibrate your camera on your own. See [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d13/tutorial_aruco_calibration.html) to know how to get camera matrix and distortion coefficients. If you need to understand the general process 
of calibrating the camera see [tutorial on camera calibration](https://docs.opencv.org/master/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)

Comment: Thanks, Sushi but do you have a video or something that makes it easier to understand.